# How to drag and drop images from Windows Explorer to Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

When I drag and drop image files from Windows Explorer to Excel,
nothing happens. 
Can you make it work?

I’m particularly interested in jpg/png or ico files,
but I’d like to be able to do it with all image types.

I have been inserting them using Excel’s insert image features,
but it doesn't seem to be super productive. 
I was looking for a faster, efficient option to improve productivity.

Comment: what type of images? jpg? png?

Comment: I tried jpeg, jpg and gif but no luck with Excel 2007

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Excel 2007 or greater, try the shortcut key <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

That might be the fastest way.

Comment: I was specifically looking for the drag / drop feature to improve productivity.

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't think there is one that's why I tried to give you the next best thing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround: drag into MS Word and then drag into Excel.

Definitely better then going through the Insert system.

Comment: You can open it in Paint as well, and select all, copy and paste into Excel.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way I've found is to copy the image itself by viewing it first and then copy it into the clipboard. Then it can be pasted into Excel.

Comment: what version of Excel you use?

Comment: 16.13.1 for Mac (Office 365)

Comment: Question was tagged Windows Explorer and clearly asks for a windows solution. Office for Mac is not windows. This solution doesn't work in windows.